# Compile android Libcurl.a cause "no such instruction: `rev16 %ax,%ax'" error;

Tags: android, libcurl

I'm try to compile libcurl.a for android on Ubuntu; but now i had some problems;

after set PATH:
 export LDFLAGS="-L/data/NDK/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-I /data/NDK/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include"

success done;

./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-ftp --disable-gopher --disable-file --disable-imap --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps --disable-pop3 --disable-proxy --disable-rtsp --disable-smtp --disable-telnet --disable-tftp --without-gnutls --without-libidn --without-librtmp --without-ssl --disable-dict

success done;

then i "make";

it throws me this error:

**connect.c: Assembler messages:
connect.c:634: Error: no such instruction: `rev16 %ax,%ax'
connect.c:427: Error: no such instruction:`rev16 %ax,%ax'
connect.c:457: Error: no such instruction: `rev16 %ax,%ax'
connect.c:420: Error: no such instruction:`rev16 %ax,%ax'
connect.c:387: Error: no such instruction: `rev16 %ax,%ax'**

help me plz; tks;

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue ? Got stuck at same place.